# How to get the text of textbox to textblock in another xaml? c# windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

**Code in my MainPage.xaml**

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="376,350,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="14" Width="113" 
        Text="{Binding TextBox1Text}"/>
```

**Code in my MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public string TextBox1Text
{
    get { return this.txtBox1.Text; }
    set { this.txtBox1.Text = value; }
}
```

**Code in my Page2.xaml**

```
MainPage main = new MainPage();
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    txtBlock1.Text = main.TextBox1Text;
}
```

when i run this there no text that output in my textblock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler way to do that is to pass parameters between pages:

`MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), textBox1.Text);
}
```

And in `Page2.xaml.cs`:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    textBlock1.Text = e.Parameter.ToString();
}
```

**Edit**: It appears that you want to pass multiple parameters. You can package multiple objects in a `List<T>` collection or create a class:

```
public class NavigationPackage
{
    public string TextToPass { get; set; }
    public ImageSource ImgSource { get; set; }
}
```

In your current page:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationPackage np = new NavigationPackage();
    np.TextToPass = textBox1.Text;
    np.ImgSource = bg2.Source;

    Frame.Navigate(typeof(MultiGame), np);
 }
```

In `MultiGame.cs` you can "unpack" the items from the class:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationPackage np = (NavigationPackage)e.Parameter;

    newTextBlock.Text = np.TextToPass;
    newImage.Source = np.ImgSource;
}
```

Comment: how can i navigate the image source and textbox text at the same time?

i try this but it doesnt work 

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MultiGame), bg2.Source);
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MultiGame), txtBox1.text);
        }

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new instance of `MainPage`. `TextBox1Text` isn't initialized with a value.

If you want it to be a value shared across all of your pages either create a static class or declare your property in the App.cs file

This would be the same as saying.

```
MyCustomClass x = new MyCustomClass();
x.StringProperty = "Im set";

x = new MYCustomClass();
```

`x.StringProperty` isn't set now.

Comment: can you make it with my on code so that i can understand it im really new in making c# and xaml pardon me!

Comment: I can't make it anymore clear than I have. Research Static Classes and Class Instances if you need more explanation of why your code isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
In MainPage.cs

```
public static MainPage current;

public static Textbox txtbox

Public mainpage()
{
     Current = this;
     txtbox = this.yourtextboxInXAML;
}
```

In page2.cs

```
public Mainpage.Current.txtbox txtbox;
```

Now you can use your Mainpage XAML textbox in page2 when ever you want.