# Passing values from one page to another on a Windows phone project

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, data-transfer

I am trying to work out how to transfer string value from one windows phone app page to the next, following [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff626521(v=vs.105).aspx) but I get an error that reads "The name 'NavigationService' does not exist in the current context".

There is a textbox and a button on page1. There is only a TEXTBLOCK on page 2. I wish to enter a string in the textbox of page 1, and when the button is clicked, the page 2 shows up with the text from the textbox (of page 1) in the textblock of page 2.

For the button click even in page 1, I entered this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml?msg=" + Texbox_page1.Text, UriKind.Relative));

}
```

In the OnNavigatedTo method, in page 2, I entered

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    string msg = "";

    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg", out msg))
    {
        Textblock_nickname_display.Text = msg;
    }
}
```

What am I missing? If there is n easier way to do this, please share!

I've spend almost 4 hours trying to figure this out, watching YouTube videos and what not!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And I get "The name 'NavigationContext' does not exist in the current context" on the OnNavigatedTo page (page 2)..

Comment: What type of Windows Phone app are you creating? WinPhone7? WinPhone 8? WinPhone 8 Silverlight? WinPhone 8.x Universal/Store?

Comment: The project is Universal App, but I am doing all the stuffs for just the Windows Phone 8.1 using Windows Runtime

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8.1 - Page Navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154359/windows-phone-8-1-page-navigation)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have

```
using System.Windows.Navigation;
```

Also, make sure your pages inherit from the proper base class.

```
public class SecondPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

...

}
```

**EDIT:**
Right click your project in the solution explorer and click Add > Reference and search for **PresentationFramework**.  Adding that reference should give you the namespace you need.

Comment: Hi, thats the problem.. It throws an this error: The type or namespace name 'Navigation' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: /that is when i add "using System.Windows.Navigation;"

Comment: I also tried this on page 2

            public Page2(string str_Value) //overloading the constuctor
            {
                this.InitializeComponent();
                Textblock_nickname_display.Text = str_Value;

            }
then on the button click event of page 1, this is what i put

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Page2 page2 new Page2(Texbox_nickname_extraction.Text);

        }

Comment: Manage to fix it following this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884096/how-to-get-the-text-of-textbox-to-textblock-in-another-xaml-c-sharp-windows-sto

But thnx for looking though :)

Answer (score 0):

Your project is Windows Phone 8.1 (Universal), So `NavigationService` isn't exist any longer.

You can use ***Frame.Navigate*** method in WP 8.1.

And below is my answer about Page Navigation in Windows Phone 8.1, please read it:

[Windows Phone 8.1 - Page Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154359/windows-phone-8-1-page-navigation/23154444#23154444)